# Dynamic Proxy with password

Tags: ssh, password, proxy

I need to setup a proxy on my localbox to redirect some requests to another network. I am doing it in the following way

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:22022 some-external-host
```

In this case every time i try run this command in script it is always asks for a password, is it possible to pass a password to this command programatically and not to type it every time i run this script? 
Public keys is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using keys for an automated logon:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Comment: yes, but keys are not an option for me, cause it requires work from admins from external server that is not possible for the moment.